# Java Regex Ordering with \b

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I am facing a weird problem with Java Regex when combined with the word-boundary `\b`.
Read through [Oracle - RegexBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) and [RegularExpressions - WordBoundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Below is my regex (Java String) (for a email address)

```
"\\b[A-Z0-9._!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{}|~]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"
```

This regex matches the email `test$@example.com` but not `$test@example.com`.

However, when I remove `\b` (Java String `\\b`), it matches both the email. This is the case for all the special characters in the regex.

Whats happening with `\b` in the ordering of regex? I though that `` [A-Z0-9._!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{}|~]+ `` should match text in any order irrespective of `\b`

**Code Snippet:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidationUtil {

    private static final String EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = "\\b[A-Z0-9._!#$%&'*+-/=?^`{}|~]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$";
    private static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        if (email == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Matcher matcher = EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

After this issue, I moved the regex validation to [apache-commons EmailValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html). But still curious why this weird behavior.

I went through many stackoverflow topics on issue with `\b`, but couldn't find a related one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) you link to:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - ...

The first character, `$`, is not a word character, so the `\b` isn't matched at the start of the string and therefore the entire regex isn't matched.

Comment: It also says ``Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.`` So your point and this point meant that the first character should always be a word character?

Comment: @Baskar: There are 3 different (type of) positions, and what you quoted is another possible position for the boundary.

Comment: @Baskar: That other point doesn't apply when you're matching a regex that begins with a `\b`. Only the first point does (that's why I only quoted the first point).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to place unescaped hyphen character either at first or at last position in character class. Second **you cannot use word boundary before `$`** since `$` is not considered a word character.

This modified regex **lookbehind based** should work for you:

```
(?<!\w)[\w.!#$%&'*+/=?^`{}|~-]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK2bD2/2)

Here `(?<!\w)` means match if not preceded by a word character.

Comment: `(?<!\w)` is still not a substitute for \b because this assumes that there is a character prior to the beginning of your "word". If it is at the start of the string it won't work. I guess you could try pre-pending a fake character.

Comment: I am not sure whether its substitute for `\b`, but it matches `test$@example.com` and `$test@example.com`. Thanks.  
However, I am not looking for alternative for `\b`, rather interested in understanding more on `\b`.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss: `(?<!\w)` doesn't assume that there is a character in front - when there is no character in front, `\w` can't match and the assertion simply return true and proceed to the sequel.

Comment: @anubhava: `[^\B]` doesn't make any sense in Java regex, IIRC.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have checked before commenting, I guess that is PCRE specific.

Comment: @anubhava: It is not. It simply degenerates to `[^B]`. (And time to file a bug to regex101)

Comment: @nhahtdh Cool. I never realized that Java regex had such capabilities. I better brush up on it. Just looked at it in Eclipse  CTRL+F, and it works like you said.